# count lines with matching pattern from log file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

My abc.log contains below entries (snippet):

```
...
INFO #my-service# #add# id=67986324423 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #add# id=43536343643 isTrial=false
INFO #my-service# #add# id=43634636365 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #add# id=67986324423 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #delete# id=43634636365 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #delete# id=56543435355 isTrial=false
...
```

I want to count the lines which are having unique ids with `#add#` attribute in them & having `isTrial=true`.

For above snippet, the output should be 2

Can any one proivide me linux command which I can run against above log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just `awk`:

```bsh
# Count unique line
$ awk '$3~"add"&&$5~"true"&&!u[$4]++{++c}END{print c}' file
2

# Print unique lines
$ awk '$3~"add"&&$5~"true"&&!u[$4]++' file
INFO #my-service# #add# id=67986324423 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #add# id=43634636365 isTrial=true
```

Or just `sort` and `grep`

```bsh
$ sort -uk4,4 file | grep "#add#.*true" 
INFO #my-service# #add# id=67986324423 isTrial=true
INFO #my-service# #add# id=43634636365 isTrial=true

$ sort -uk4,4 file | grep -c "#add#.*true"
2
```

Comment: Fewer processes … I like it +1

Comment: I think this could be cleaner and easier to grok (e.g. `awk '$3 == "#add#" && $5 == "isTrial=true" { ++c; } END { print c; }'` or `awk '$3 == "#add#" && $5 == "isTrial=true" { seen[$4] = 1; } END { for (i in seen) print i; }`, respectively - may or may not be more efficient, though), but +1 for the right idea...

Comment: @twalberg the first script you suggest doesn't account for unique id, I take you point on comparing fields over line matching however.

Comment: @sudo_O Doh... right... My thinko there - so the first one should actually be as you had it for the action bits : `awk '$3 == "#add#" && $5 == "isTrial=true" { seen[$4] = 1; } END { print length(seen); }`. Now if only I could edit comments...

Comment: Which one will run fast...using just awk or using grep cut sort uniq?

Comment: I would think just the awk solution but both sould be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

this one-liner gives you result 2

```
awk -F'#add# id=' '$2~/true/{a[$2]}END{print length(a)}' abc.log
```

this one-liner gives you the two unique lines

```
awk -F'#add# id=' '$2~/true/&&!a[$2]++' abc.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `grep`, `cut`, `sort` and `wc`:

```
grep '#add#.*isTrial=true$' /path/to/file | cut -f4 | sort -u | wc -l
```

Customize the regular expression to your liking (being more strict/less strict about what lines it matches).

(`cut -f4 -d' '` if your delimiter is space instead of tab)

Comment: Wait : `cut -f4` does nothing there !

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoter gave an explanation why he thinks this answer is so bad or incorrect?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm curious: won't that `.*` be greedy?

Answer (score -1):

this will count too

```
grep "isTrial=true" abc.log | grep "#add#" | awk ' { print $4 }' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: thanks...if the id contains alphabets, will the above command still work?